# Is there a way to get the sample weights that were used to fit a scikit-learn estimator?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Many sklearn estimators support two weighting schemes:

- *Per-class weights:* given when creating the estimator object (e.g. `clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight={'Cat':0.4, 'Dog':0.6}`)
- *Per-sample weights:* given when fitting a created object (e.g. `clf.fit(X, y, sample_weight=[0.1, 0.1, 0.8]`)

For an *already fitted estimator*, I can get the per-class weights with `clf.get_params()['class_weight']`.

But what's the right way (if any) to get, given a fitted estimator, the *per-sample weights* that were used?

Comment: A quick search of the source code, e.g. RandomForestClassifier's, doesn't find anywhere that `sample_weight` gets saved as a class attribute.  I suspect that was a conscious decision: the sample weights are directly tied to the dataset, which also doesn't get saved for later use; that's why `sample_weight` appears in the `fit` method rather than the class instantiation.

Comment: Thanks @BenReiniger - would you like to re-post this as an answer? It's actually pretty good, and I'll accept it if no better idea comes up.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/448780/232706, https://stackoverflow.com/q/60099960/10495893

Comment: Update: I removed the two other cross-posts, you can clear the comments (links won't be active anymore).

Comment: The links are operable for anyone with sufficient privileges.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search of the source code, e.g. RandomForestClassifier's, doesn't find anywhere that `sample_weight` gets saved as a class attribute. I suspect that was a conscious decision: the sample weights are directly tied to the dataset, which also doesn't get saved for later use; that's why `sample_weight` appears in the fit method rather than the class instantiation.